# Overloading operator == in a class that uses another class

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, operator-overloading

I'm beginning to learn C++ and object-oriented programming and I'm struggling to understand what is wrong with my assignment.
I have two classes: point and line to define points and lines in a Cartesian plan. I'm trying to overload == operator for line class.

Definition of class in point.h:

```
#ifndef POINT_H
#define POINT_H

#include <iostream>

class point
{
    public:

        // Default constructor
        // Initializes (x,y) = (0,0)
        point();

        // Overloaded constructor
        point(double , double);

        // Copy constructor
        point(const point& );

        // Sets new value for x
        void set_x (double );

        // Sets new value for y
        void set_y(double );

        // Returns value of x
        double get_x();

        // Returns value of y
        double get_y();

        // Overloads = operator
        void operator = (const point& );

    private:
        double x, y;

};

// Overloads == operator
bool operator ==(point& , point& );

#endif
```

Implementation in point.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "point.h"

using namespace std;

// Default constructor
// Initializes (x,y) = (0,0)
point::point() {
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
}

// Overloaded constructor
point::point(double X, double Y) {
    x = X;
    y = Y;
}

// Copy constructor
point::point(const point& p) {
    this->x = p.x;
    this->y = p.y;
}

// Sets new value for x
void point::set_x (double X) {
    x = X;
}

// Sets new value for y
void point::set_y(double Y) {
    y = Y;
}

// Returns value of x
double point::get_x() {
    return x;
}

// Returns value of y
double point::get_y() {
    return y;
}

// Overloads = operator
void point::operator = (const point& source) {
    this->x = source.x;
    this->y = source.y;
}

// Overloads == operator
bool operator == (point& p1, point& p2) {
    if(p1.get_x() == p2.get_x() && p1.get_y() == p2.get_y()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The line.h file:

```
#ifndef LINE_H
#define LINE_H

#include <iostream>
#include "point.h"

class line {
    public:

        // line = X axis
        line();

        // line passes through (0,0) and
        // the point provided by programmer
        line(point );

        // line passes through the 2
        // points provided
        line(point , point );

        // Copy Constructor
        line(line& );

        // Overloads = operator
        void operator = (line& );

        // Overloads == operator
        friend bool operator ==(const line& , const line& );


    private:
        point p1;
        point p2;
};

#endif
```

The line.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "point.h"
#include "line.h"

using namespace std;

// line = X axis
line::line() {
    p1.set_x(0);
    p1.set_y(0);
    p2.set_x(100);
    p2.set_y(0);
}

// line passes through (0,0) and point p
line::line(point p) {
    p1.set_x(0);
    p1.set_y(0);
    p2.set_x(p.get_x());
    p2.set_y(p.get_y());
}

// line passes through the 2 points p & q
line::line(point p, point q) {
    p1.set_x(p.get_x());
    p1.set_y(p.get_y());
    p2.set_x(q.get_x());
    p2.set_y(q.get_y());
}

// Copy Constructor
line::line(line& L) {
    this->p1 = L.p1;
    this->p2 = L.p2;
}

// Overloads = operator
void line::operator = (line& L) {
    this->p1.set_x(L.p1.get_x());
    this->p1.set_y(L.p1.get_y());
    this->p2.set_x(L.p2.get_x());
    this->p2.set_y(L.p2.get_y());
}

bool operator ==(const line& L1, const line& L2) {
    if((L1.p1 == L2.p1) && (L1.p2 == L2.p2)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The == operator for line doesn't work... The code compiles without any error or warning but when I try to use it... it will give me a message: **Segmentation fault: 11**.

I'm calling these methods in this way:

```
int main (int argc, char const* argv[])
{
    point p1(10, 10), p2(13, 18.5), p3(0,0);
    line l1, l2(p1,p3), l3(p1,p2);
    l1 = l2;

    if(l1 == l2) {
        cout << "l1 == le" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "l1 != l2" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How are you checking for equality ?

Comment: Other than const correctness in the Point equality operator and incorrect case in the class names in both equality operators, there's nothing obviously wrong with the code. You'll need to give more information on what your calling code looks like, possibly with a call stack at the time of the segmentation fault.

Comment: @Jagannath I just need to compare if p1 from l1 is equal to p1 from l2, and p2 from l1 is equal to p2 from l2.

Comment: where is your `bool operator ==(const Line& L1, const Line& L2)` function defined?  Is it in the same .cpp file as `main`?  It would need to be a friend of/within Line in order to access the private members in Line, `p1` and `p2`, or else you would be getting a compiler error, hence the reason for my first question.

Comment: Can you add some code to confirm your Point == operator is working correctly? The source of the problem could be there.

Comment: @franji1 I've edited the code... I forgot about that... My bool operator ==(const Line& L1, const Line& L2) is defined inside the class as a friend class... My bool operator == (Point& p1, Point& p2) is defined outside the Point class... But I tested and this one is working...

Comment: `l1 = l2;` - I guess the problem is here, but you haven't posted complete code we can test or reason about...

Comment: @Jessica I see where you declare `operator==` overload for points in point.h, but I do not see declaration of `operator==` for lines in line.h.  How will main(.cpp) know to look for/link against the overload instead of a compiler generated `operator==` for lines (the `friend` declaration in the `line` class is not enough, I don't believe, for clients of the overload)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix your `operator==` for `point`. It should take `const&` like this

```
bool operator == (const point& p1, const point& p2)
```

to fix it you need to mark getters with `const` in header

```
    // Returns value of x
    double get_x() const;

    // Returns value of y
    double get_y() const;
```

and in source

```
// Returns value of x
double point::get_x() const {
    return x;
}

// Returns value of y
double point::get_y() const {
    return y;
}
```

This should do the trick, output is

> l1 == le